# Caliburn.micro and devexpress: insert tabs (dockpanel) from viewmodel when user clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, caliburn.micro

Cheers all,

I'm searching to use the devexpress tool in my visual c# project (vs2013). I'm also using caliburn.micro and i've inserted the Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress reference. So, this is my environment.

The problem: I want create a container, where you can open some predefined tabs. You can navigate in the  open tabs, close them and open others.

I'm in stuck with the integration of devexpress and caliburn. Without caliburn and mostly **without MVVM pattern**, it's easy. But how can I do this using my **viewModel**?

The result I want is like the example "Simple MDI" in [[the official caliburn.micro documentation1]](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2C%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation). Instead of the button "open tab", I've my menu in the upper side and, depending on which button is clicked, I want open the relative dockpanel/tab.

Now, in the xaml file, my container is a devexpress object, the "DocumentGroup". My goal is to add dynamically the DocumentPanel(s), like written above.

Is it clear the problem? Some ideas for solution?

UPDATE: in my viewModel I have:

```
namespace **.ViewModels
{
class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public void addT() {
        Debug.WriteLine("start");
        ActivateItem(new ucImpiantiViewModel());
        Debug.WriteLine("end");
    }
}
```

}

And in the xaml I have:

```
...
<dxd:DocumentGroup x:Name="Items" ItemHeight="3*" SelectedTabIndex="0">
...
```

I thought this way was good, but still nothing.. the good new is only that the console.writeline are working!

Comment: I am afraid Caliburn does not know how to handle the DockLayoutManager and its DocumentGroups directly. May be your task can be accomplished with using a special extension for Caliburn: [Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress](https://calmicrodevexpress.codeplex.com/)...

Comment: I already use it, I've written it! :-) But there is no documentation about this tool! :-(